# Can anyone help me resolve this db query error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webmatrix

On execution, I get this error message:

```
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 116,

Token in error = No ]

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 116,Token in error = No ]
```

Source Error:

```
Line 40: "Nationality, Passport No, Occupation, PaymentMethod) " +
Line 41: "VALUES ( @0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10 )";
Line 42: db.Execute(bookingSql,
Line 43: surname,
Line 44: name,
```

Here's My code below:
P.s I am new to programming help me out!!

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Make your reservations";
    var surname="";
    var name="";
    var email="";
    var arrivalDate = DateTime.MinValue;
    var departureDate=DateTime.MinValue;
    var city = "";
    var country = "";
    var nationality = "";
    var passportno = "";
    var occupation="";
    var paymentmethod=""; 
    if (IsPost)
    {
        surname = Request["surname"];
        name = Request["name"];
        email = Request["email"];
        arrivalDate = Request["arrivalDate"].AsDateTime();
        departureDate = Request["departureDate"].AsDateTime();
        city = Request["city"];
        country = Request["country"];
        nationality = Request["nationality"];
        passportno = Request["passportno"];
        occupation = Request["occupation"];
        paymentmethod = Request["paymentmethod"];

        // Validate Reservation Details
        if (name.IsEmpty()) {
            ModelState.AddError("name", "Your name is required.");
        }
        if (surname.IsEmpty()) {
            ModelState.AddError("surname", "Your Surname is required.");
        }

        // Save Reservation
        var db = Database.Open("ElimGuestHouseData");
        var bookingSql = "INSERT INTO Booking (Surname, Name, EmailAddress," +
            "ArrivalDate, DepartureDate, City, Country, " +
            "Nationality, Passport No, Occupation, PaymentMethod) " +
            "VALUES ( @0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10 )";

        db.Execute(bookingSql, surname, name, email, arrivalDate, 
            departureDate, city, country, nationality, passportno, 
            occupation, paymentmethod);
        Response.Redirect("Reservationcomplete");

    }
}


<h1>Reservation</h1>
<form action="Reservation" method="post">
    <p>
    @Html.Label("Surname:", "surname")
    @Html.TextBox("surname", surname, new { maxlength = "50" } )
    </p>
    <p>
    @Html.Label("Name: ", "name")
    @Html.TextBox("name", name, new { maxlength = "50" } )
    @Html.ValidationMessage("address1")
    </p>
    <p>
    @Html.Label("Email Address: ", "email")
    @Html.TextBox("email", email, new { maxlength = "50" } )
    @Html.ValidationMessage("town")
    </p>
    <p>
    @Html.Label("Arrival Date: ", "arrivalDate")
    @Html.TextBox("arrivalDate", arrivalDate.ToShortDateString())
    @Html.ValidationMessage("arrivalDate")
    </p>
    <p>
    @Html.Label("Departure Date: ", "departureDate")
    @Html.TextBox("departureDate", departureDate.ToShortDateString())
    @Html.ValidationMessage("departureDate")
    </p>
    <p>
    @Html.Label("City: ", "city")
    @Html.TextBox("city", city, new { maxlength = "20" } )
    </p>
    <p>
    @Html.Label("Country: ", "country")
    @Html.TextBox("country", country, new { maxlength = "50" } )
    </p>

    <p>
    @Html.Label("Nationality: ", "nationality")
    @Html.TextBox("nationality", nationality, new { maxlength = "50" } )
    </p>
    <p>
    @Html.Label("Passport No: ", "passportno")
    @Html.TextBox("passportno", passportno, new { maxlength = "50" } )
    </p>
    <p>
    @Html.Label("Occupation: ", "occupation")
    @Html.TextBox("occupation", occupation, new { maxlength = "50" } )
    </p>
    <p>
    @Html.Label("PaymentMethod: ", "paymentmethod")
    @{
        var paymentmethodList = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "cas", Text = "Cash" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "depos", Text = "Bank Deposit" },
        };
    }

    @Html.DropDownList("paymentmethod", "Not selected", paymentmethodList, paymentmethod, null)
    </p>
    <h2>Confirm Reservation</h2>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Place Reservation"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query should be -

```
...
"Nationality, [Passport No], Occupation
...
```

If column name has spaces, it need to be inside square brackets - `[xxx]`.